# Conversión de valores a string

Tags: c#, sql-server, aplicación-web, asp.net-web-api

```
 int Rol = 0;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ToString());
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");

        if (!IsPostBack && Session["Usuario"] != null)
        {
            Rol = Convert.ToInt32(Session["IdRol"].ToString()); //ACÁ ME SEÑALA EL ERROR
            Datos();
            Permisos(Rol);
        }
    }
```

La verdad.. no sé porque me da error justo ahí, aplico lo mismo en muchas conversiones y ahora me salió este error

> System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'

Comment: Coloca antes del error var algo =  Session["IdRol"]; y en la linea del error un punto de interrupción, luego inspecciona que valor tiene la variable "algo"

Comment: @Yussef me devuelve 0 incluso cuando le cambio de valor en la base de datos sigue retornando 0 y el nombre de la base de datos está bien esscrito.

Comment: Me estás diciendo que `Session["IdRol"].ToString()` es igual a cero siempre y que cuando lo conviertes a Int te arroja una excepción ?

Comment: Como guardas o en que momento creas l Session["IdRol"]. Supuestamente asumes que cuando entra a la página debe existir Session["Usuario"]. Podrías poner en que parte creas esas variabl3s de Session? Definitivamente IdRol esta en Blanco o tiene un formato invalido.